# Get distance from PHP function

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate the distance form `lat` and `long`. The problem is that when I am getting the distance form the database and pass those values to the distance function then I am running into an issue.

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('distance')) {
    function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
        $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
        $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
        $dist = acos($dist);
        $dist = rad2deg($dist);
        $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        $unit = strtoupper($unit);

        if ($unit == "K") {
            return ($miles * 1.609344);
        } else if ($unit == "N") {
            return ($miles * 0.8684);
        } else {
            return $miles;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my query:

```
if (!empty($usersInfo)) {
    foreach($usersInfo as $key => $users) {
        echo $ridefrom = $users['ride_from'];
        echo $rideto = $users['ride_to'];
    }
}
```

The output of this query is:

> 32.9697, -96.8032229.46786, -98.535062118447689133

So I want pass these value like this:

```
$ridefrom = distance($users['ride_from']);
```

But my query does not show any result.

Comment: You can do the calculation in the query itself. https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator#finding-locations-with-mysql

Comment: user3783243@ok I don't have idea abut this

Comment: I added a Google doc that has it listed, see updated comment.

Comment: Your `distance()` function expects 5 arguments, but you pass only one -- `$users['ride_from']`. I don't know the format of your input data, and thus cannot suggest you what changes you need to do to make it work, but that's definitely the point where changes must be done.

Comment: user3783243 @Thanks for this. I have read this doc but I am trying to get distance with php function

Comment: alx @$ridefrom =$users['ride_from'];//this is from lat long
                   $rideto = $users['ride_to'];//this is too lat long

Comment: alx@ all thing run if I used this 
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") . " Miles<br>";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") . " Kilometers<br>";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "N") . " Nautical Miles<br>";

Comment: @newdeveloper The `@` needs to be before the username for notifications to be sent. The distance will be turned to you with the query results.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to fetch records from a DB within a certain distance?

There is an equation called the Haversine formula, which uses spherical trigonometry to calculate areas within a certain distance! It looks like this:

```
R = earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km)
Δlat = lat2− lat1
Δlong = long2− long1
a = sin²(Δlat/2) + cos(lat1).cos(lat2).sin²(Δlong/2)
c = 2.atan2(√a, √(1−a))
d = R.c
Angles need to be in radians to pass to Trigonometric functions
```

Which is a bit mumbo jumbo to me, but makes more sense when made into an SQL statement:

```
SELECT *, 
 ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(55.864237) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
 * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-4.251806) ) + sin( radians(55.864237) ) 
 * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM postcodes HAVING distance < 20 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1;
```

Here I check for any area within 20 miles, but you can make this as short or long as you want.  The 3959 figure at the start of the query is the number used for miles, if you are using kilometres you should change this number to 6371.  I have limited it to 1 row, as I only want the closest match, however you may want to change this in other situations!

I hope this helps you! :-)